# Show Raspberry Pi Infos on a webpage

Tags: pi-3b+

I want to make a control-website and show raspberry pi information on that. I heard about flask, but is that the right tool, to get the cpu temperatur for example? Or how can I do that with php?

Comment: break the task down.  start with a hello world website and figure out how to read each piece of info you want to show on that site separately.  that way you can try different server side code execution mechanisms to find "the right tool"

Answer (score -1):

I think python it's better and easier to use for the task you wrote since php sucks... Flask is a good choice and also FastAPI (has a performance near node/python since uses asyncronous coroutines, with some limitations when you rely on packages that are not async/await like request which blocks the program until the response is returned)

Then, there's the front-end where I recommend you to use vue3 instead of react because it's easier to pick and understand. From the web app you must call the API that exposes the sensor data to get the data back and axios is the right tool for that

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).